# Enable brotli compression in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to use ClickHouse (version 23.2.1) to query parquet data stored in S3. The parquet data is stored using Brotli compression.

But I am getting the following error -

```
Code: 33. DB::ParsingException: Error while reading Parquet data: NotImplemented: Support for codec 'brotli' not built: While executing ParquetBlockInputFormat: While executing S3. (CANNOT_READ_ALL_DATA) (version 23.2.1.2537 (official build))
```

Is support for brotli compression not built into official ClickHouse builds?

How can I enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently ClickHouse doesn's support reading Parquet files with brotli compression, but it will be added in the next release 23.3.

PS: I work in ClickHouse.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Looking forward to it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its currently only supported for HTTP transport and not the compression of files.